# Cancel Excel Edit Mode after changing chart values in Word document

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts

I have a VB app which I need it to modify the values dynamically for some pre-created charts in a Word Document. I have a number of charts which need to be changed based on data read from a SQL server. My problem is I can change the values for the first chart in the Word document but my code crashes when I try and change any other chart values in the document.

I have created separate variables for each of the charts in the document which is fine and then I have:

```
    Dim chartShape As Word.InlineShape = objDoc.InlineShapes.Item(1)
    Dim oDedupeSpace As Word.InlineShape = objDoc.InlineShapes.Item(2)

    With chartShape.Chart.ChartData
        .Activate()
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = nTotalUnique
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value = (nTotalFiles - nTotalUnique)
        .Workbook.Close()
    End With

    ' Now Update The Pie Chart For Duplication (Storage)
    With oDedupeSpace.Chart.ChartData
        .Activate()
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = nTotalUniqueSpace
        .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value = (nTotalDisk - nTotalUniqueSpace)
        .Workbook.Close()
    End With
```

The problem is when it comes to make the changes to the second chart the error message suggests VB thinks I am trying to create a new chart and mentions cancelling Excel Edit mode.

Any ideas how I cancel the edit mode from the first change before I make the next changes?

[Pop up error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is4Cu.png)

Code error screen shot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8PHq.png)

Comment: You should provide a clear enough description of the problem (and/or the original error message), not something as vague as "suggests...". Also you should include relevant parts of the code and ideally indicate the exact point where the code is crashing. Just by looking at your sample code, it is unclear what is the parent variable of all the `.Workbook` references (it seems `Chardata`, but I don't think that this is the case). You might be provoking the error yourself by trying to access a closed workbook (after `.Workbook.Close()`). But this is just a blind assumption. Please, ask properly.

Comment: Sorry the error is flagged against the second .Activate() in the code snippet above.

Comment: Sorry for the poor quality of information this is my first post, I have updated the original post to show the declaration of the 2 object variables. I have also added 2 screen shots of the errors that are displayed. I hope this meets with your standards

Comment: It has nothing to do with my standards. It has to do with allowing anyone willing to help you to understand what is the problem (no understanding = no help for you). You shouldn't be the most interested person in writing clear enough questions; for me (or for any other potential helper), it would be much easier to just ignore your post (or eventually downvote/put it on hold).

Comment: This is still a bit unclear (and/or wrong); but it seems that .Workbook.Close() is the reponsible. According to your code, you are taking two Word shapes which are linked with an Excel file (which apparently is opened, otherwise the error would be triggered with the first attempt). You are closing this Excel file (the associated variable) with .Workbook.Close(). When you try to access this file again, you get an error. Solution: remove the first Workbook.Close().

Comment: In any case, your approach (and your exact understanding of what is going on) seems way too prone to errors for what looks like a not-too-simple situation (Word + Excel). You should better create a properly-structured code with all the required variables to open/deal with/close & properly release (-> this last point is quite important and I guess that you are not taking care of it) both the Excel and Word instances. My recommendation: do some online research, find working codes to deal with Word/Excel and improve your understanding about this whole situation.